# Memcached configuration in springboot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, memcached

I'm trying to CI a Java SpringBoot app, the app is making use of memcached.
`pom.xml` dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.sixhours</groupId>
  <artifactId>memcached-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'v created a `docker-compose.yaml` file with `memcached` container, `app` container and `nginx` as reverse proxy all running on the same network `ci_network`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  memcached:
    image: memcached:latest
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"
    networks:
      - ci_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "echo", "stats", "|", "nc", "localhost", "11211"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 5
  
  # Backend - ted-search app
  app:
    image: ted-search:latest
    depends_on:
      memcached:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - ci_network

  # Reverse Proxy - Nginx
  proxy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx    
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - app    
    networks:
      - ci_network

networks:
  ci_network:
    external: true
```

I've configured the `application.properties` file to enable memcached as follows:

```
server.port: 9191

spring.cache.type=GENERIC

# MEMCACHED CACHE
memcached.cache.servers: memcached:11211
memcached.cache.mode: static
memcached.cache.expirations: 3600, oembed:3600
memcached.cache.prefix: memcached:spring-boot
memcached.cache.namespace: namespace
memcached.cache.protocol: text


#Metrics related configurations
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true

management.metrics.distribution.percentiles-histogram.http.server.requests: true
management.metrics.distribution.sla.server.requests: 450ms
```

for some reason every time I'm running my docker compose orchestration the app is crashing with the following error:

```
18:21:03  ted-search_master-app-1        | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheAutoConfigurationValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/CacheAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No cache manager could be auto-configured, check your configuration (caching type is 'GENERIC')
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try removing the `spring.cache.type=GENERIC` from your `application.properties` and try again.

The issue you have reported is related to the cache configuration in the application itself.

In case the `spring.cache.type` is specified, the **memcached-spring-boot-starter** library will skip its auto-configuration and use **Spring Boot** cache auto-configuration instead. Being the [GENERIC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.x/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider.generic) cache type is missing proper configuration (`org.springframework.cache.Cache` bean), the application startup will fail.

You should also consider upgrading the **memcached-spring-boot-starter** to the latest version `2.5.0`.

Comment: I've removed the `spring.cache.type=GENERIC` as you offered and caching seems to work well.
Do you have any suggestions how to validate the use of memcached and make  sure my app I'm trying to CI is not using `SIMPLE` as the default caching library?

Comment: You might check the type of `org.springframework.cache.CacheManager` Spring bean, perhaps on application startup within method annotated with`@PostConstruct` annotation, having following condition inside **if** statement:`MemcachedCacheManager.class.isAssignableFrom(cacheManager.getClass())`. If this statement is `true`, everything is fine and memcached cache is used; otherwise some other cache type is used.